# SSAS memory limits

Tags: ssas

SSAS service is configured using standard settings with a low memory limit 65. Accordingly to MS it means 65% of the available RAM and hardware host has 256 GB RAM, but SSAS always stops at ~65GB and writes the information into eventlog:
"Entering Low Memory mode (Current memory consumption: 65558.4880 MB)."
It's Standard SQL 2017 Build 14.0.249.51 installed as a failover clustered instance.

Any ideas why it happens and how I can fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you using ssas multidimentional or tabular?

Answer (score 2):

based on this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2019?view=sql-server-ver16#Cross-BoxScaleLimits

your ssas standard edition has some memory limits.

- 16Gb for tabular
- 64gb for multidimensional

Comment: thank you! sometimes it's so obvious...